# Special characters as argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Im making a small calculator that takes 3 command line argument like `sh programname operand1 operator operand2` and compute its value. I want the user to only enter 3 arguments and an operator which can only be one `+,-,x,/,%,^`. The problem Im having is when the user enters `#` or `/*` the program doesn't output the right error message.

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! $# == 3 ]
    then
    echo "Usage: sh $0 operand1 operator operand2 "
    exit 1
fi

n1=$1 op=$2 n2=$3
if [ $2 == "+" ]; then  
        ans=`expr $n1 + $n2`
        echo "$ans"
elif [ $2 == "-" ]; then
    ans=`expr $n1 - $n2`
    echo "$ans"
elif [ $2 == "x" ]; then
    ans=`expr $n1 \* $n2`
    echo "$ans"
elif [ $2 == "/" ]; then
    ans=`expr $n1 / $n2`
    echo "$ans"
elif [ $2 == "%" ]; then
    ans=`expr $n1 % $n2`
    echo "$ans"
elif [ $2 == "^" ]; then
    echo $((n1**n2))
else
    echo "Error: invalid operator"
    exit 1
fi
```

When the user `2 /* 3` or `2 # 4` the program doesn't recognizes thats its 3 arguments and output the first error message when it really should output the last else statement.

Comment: Why are you using `expr` at all if `$((...))` is available?

Answer (score 3):

That's because `*` (glob expanding everything) and `#` (comment) have different meanings in shell.

Run your script with single quote around your *operator* such as:

```
# 2 '*' 3
# 2 '#' 4
```

Your program doesn't really handle `/*` case. So I am assuming it's `*`.

Answer (score 1):

This is out of your control.

The user enters the command string in their shell, which interprets `#` as "the rest of this line is a comment" and `/*` as "everything in the / directory".

Demonstration:

```
~$ echo hello # there
hello
~$ echo /*
/bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /initrd.img /initrd.img.old /lib /lib32 /lib64 /libx32 /lost+found /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var /vmlinuz /vmlinuz.old
```

You can also see the exact arguments passed from the shell into your script by doing `echo "$@"`.

Comment: Not entirely; `set -f` allows you turn off globbing, and `bash` (implied by the use of `==` with `[`) lets you disable comments in an interactive shell with `shopt -u interactive_comments`.

Comment: Yeah, but that has to be done in the user's shell -- it can't be done inside the script.